# UIAlertContoller Textfield width iOS 9

Tags: ios9, uialertcontroller, pixate

As you can see in the image below, the `TextField` of the `UIAlertController` loses it's width.

[image: Screencap of textfield width]

I have this problem while running my project that uses `PixateFreestyle` in iOS 9.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It would be useful to get more detail so that we can help answer your question. Specifically, _when_ does the `TextField` 'lose' it's width? What is the width supposed to be? What code have you implemented to do this? Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

For now i solved it adding this to the default.css file in my project:

A work-around:

```
collection-view collection-view-cell > view {
   width: 270px;
}
```

cit: >> https://github.com/Pixate/pixate-freestyle-ios/issues/178